# showframe package exceeds few points in right side

Tags: margins, geometry, lengths

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{10.9}{14}%
   \abovedisplayskip 7\p@ plus2\p@ %
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@%
   \belowdisplayshortskip 3.5\p@%
   \belowdisplayskip 7\p@ plus2\p@%
   \let\@listi\@listI}%
\normalsize%
\let\@bls\baselineskip%
\p@=1bp%%%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]


\end{document}
```

And the output shows as:

[image]

Hope the command `\p@=1bp` caused the error, but suggest that how to fix this including this tag too.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to confuse all measures by setting pt sometimes equal to bp or whatever else the line does should do?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This tag I purposely used to get the font size exactly in PDF, I know type1cm.sty did that trick, but that was not applicable if we use other fonts like Times, Palatino, etc.

Comment: Sorry this is madness. It means that 10pt has a different length than 10p@ and will break lots of packages.

Comment: `\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}` does not suffer the same issue.